# Search modify and delete from text file

Tags: java, text, replace, text-files

I'm trying to make a method search, edit and/or delete a specific word in a text file

```
 private void modifyShow() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
      Scanner input =  new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Please search for a TV Show\nExample: Simpsons");
      String tvSearch = input.nextLine();
         System.out.println("Displaying results for: " + tvSearch);
         String searchTerm = tvSearch;
         searchTerm = searchTerm.toLowerCase();
         int count = 0;
         Scanner show = new Scanner(new File("src/TVShows.txt"));
            while (show.hasNext()) {// loop
            if (show.equals(searchTerm)) { // find
               System.out.println(show);// display
             }
     } 
}
```

So it doesn't actually search the file but it opens it I believe but the while statement is throwing it off. So once it finds the word it needs to print say

```
System.out.println("Enter a new name for " + tvSearch + ".");
```

And have an input for the show and then replace it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your if `(show.equals(searchTerm))` with `if (show.next().equals(searchTerm))`,the search would work.You were actually comparing a Scanner object with the String.

Comment: But it still wont/deosn't display the search term any idea why?